# Is it possible to use Chrome DevTools to override login logic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I used the following project as the basis for the login authentication logic for an app: https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-authentication-example

When the backend was down, I manually altered the frontend to avoid the validation of user credentials to workaround the $http calls.

That made me wonder if it is possible to use **Chrome DevTools** or **Firefox's Dev Tools** to circumvent the $http call and make the app think the credentials were accepted.

So far on my own, it seems Chrome still runs the original files and any altered files on stored elsewhere and not used. But I couldn't reproduce the hack just within Chrome DevTools, but I'm not an expert and was curious if it was possible.

Comment: You can fool the client-side app. But to do anything useful, it presumably has to send something back to the server, and the server shouldn't be fooled.

Comment: @Barmar I agree. I believe the backend has some validations required for login attempts from the backend. And most requests from our data services require the auth data to be in the request headers.

Comment: Ha! While you can do all sorts of cool things in Chrome Dev tools, all changes remain local. If the changes actually take effect / any information is revealed; That would mean the end of things like internet banking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to alter client side scripts and hack any javascript code...

That is why there is a log in process the purpose of which should be assigning valid session credentials for the client side to provide to the server with each request so that it can be validated and acted upon accordingly.

Basically, your application must make sure that no sensitive information is exchanged before the valid session is established making any client side code circumvention obsolete